# Excel failing at String VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that looks like this

```
   B   C
43 XS  6
44 S   11
45 M   16
46 L   21
47 XL  26
48 XXL 31
```

I've written the formula:

```
`VLOOKUP("S",B43:C48,2)`
```

It's returning a value of 21.
WHY?! It should be returning 11!

**update** I reproduced this exact error in a different table. `VLOOKUP` works when the search value is a number, but consistently fails when I use strings.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

VLOOKUP does strange things unless you specify an "exact match" with the fourth argument, like so:

```
=VLOOKUP("S",B43:C48,2,FALSE)
```

From Excel's help file:

> VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)
>
> If `range_lookup` is TRUE, the values in the first column of table_array must be placed in ascending order: ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE; otherwise `VLOOKUP` may not give the correct value. If `range_lookup` is FALSE, table_array does not need to be sorted.

And also:

> `range_lookup` is a logical value that specifies whether you want `VLOOKUP` to find an exact match or an approximate match. If TRUE or omitted, an approximate match is returned. In other words, if an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than `lookup_value` is returned. If `FALSE`, `VLOOKUP` will find an exact match. If one is not found, the error value `#N/A` is returned.

Comment: Just a guess why: to determine a rough match from an unsorted list would be infeasibly expensive because you may have to iterate over the list a great many times.

Comment: @Ciaran Keating: I think you are right. Excel probably uses a binary search by default. That would explain the wording in the help file and the bizarre result in hatorade's example.

Answer (score 4):

Also, mismatching format types is causing you problems. (One cell is formatted as containing numbers, and the other is formatted as containing text). See problem/solution #2 on this page:

[Solutions to Three Common Problems when Using VLOOKUP()](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2010/06/10/solutions-to-three-common-problems-when-using-vlookup/)