# Excel Lookup Column 2 and Display Percentage Based On Letter

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, lookup

I want to use Excel to lookup Column 2 and display the percentage in Column 1, based on the letters shown.

```
=LOOKUP(A2,{"VL","L","M","H","VH"},{"90%","75%","50%","25%","10%"})
```

This seems to work for VL & M correctly; however, L & H do not display anything and VH displays 10%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably face problems that are caused by lookup finding "L" also in "VL".

Use VLOOKUP with exact matching instead.

http://www.excelfunctions.net/Vlookup-Example-Exact-Match.html

Comment: Looking even further, I find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762174/excel-failing-at-string-vlookup